# how to add product subscription field in woocommerce plugin

Tags: custom-field, plugins

i've a site in which a product is available for subscription and plans are 1 month, 3 month, 6 month, 12 month and price is vary according to plan. notify the user before 2 day of expiring of subscription

Comment: Please, provide more information about the problem. Some code, what you have tried and where you get stuck. - read [this article](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to offer an answer that isn't too much more than a link, but well the question itself is very weak and most importantly there's little incentive to build this yourself when it already exists as a plugin:

http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/

You could either create different products for each of the subscription plans, or now it does support variable subscriptions.. so you could just do the different monthly plans as a variation of the same produce.

The only thing I couldn't vouch for would be the expiration warnings. Otherwise it is a really good plugin.... and you would definitely spend more than $99 hiring someone else to do it or in time to figure it out yourself.